# Batched index_fill in PyTorch

Tags: pytorch, numpy-indexing

I have an index tensor of size `(2, 3)`:

```
>>> index = torch.empty(6).random_(0,8).view(2,3)
tensor([[6., 3., 2.],
        [3., 4., 7.]])
```

And a value tensor of size `(2, 8)`:

```
>>> value = torch.zeros(2,8)
tensor([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

I want to set the element in `value` to `1` by the index along `dim=-1`.** The output should be like:

```
>>> output
tensor([[0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1.]])
```

I tried `value[range(2), index] = 1` but it triggers an error. I also tried `torch.index_fill` but it doesn't accept batched indices. `torch.scatter` requires creating an extra tensor of size `2*8` full of `1`, which consumes unnecessary memory and time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually use [`torch.Tensor.scatter_`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.scatter_.html#torch.Tensor.scatter_) by setting the `value` (*int*) option instead of the `src` option (*Tensor*).

```
>>> value.scatter_(dim=-1, index=index.long(), value=1)

>>> value
tensor([[0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 1., 1., 0., 0., 1.]])
```

Make sure the `index` is of type *int64* though.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you Ivan. How could I forget the value argument!

Comment: It's actually nowhere to be seen on the documentation page of `torch.Tensor.scatter`...

Comment: Checked it. I think it's an issue.